# How to query data in MySQL using different values in same field or column as filters?

Tags: mysql

I have the following sample table

```
id  userId  userType
--------------------
10  11111   user
10  11111   biller
11  22222   user
11  22222   biller
12  33333   user
12  99999   biller
13  44444   user
13  44444   biller
14  55555   user
14  88888   biller
```

How can I get data that have different userIds for both userTypes 'user' and 'biller' with the same id? Ie for the above, I should get

```
id  userId  userType
--------------------
12  33333   user
12  99999   biller
14  55555   user
14  88888   biller
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with a self join:

```
select t1.*
from tablename t1 inner join tablename t2
on t2.id = t1.id and t2.userid <> t1.userid 
and ('user', 'biller') in ((t1.usertype, t2.usertype), (t2.usertype, t1.usertype));
```

Or, if in the column `usertype` there aren't any values other than `'user'` and `'biller'`:

```
select t1.*
from tablename t1 inner join tablename t2
on t2.id = t1.id and t2.userid <> t1.userid 
and t2.usertype <> t1.usertype;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=5425437cddb6459fe3af5e98a48efd45).
Results:

```
> id | userId | userType
> -: | -----: | :-------
> 12 |  99999 | biller  
> 12 |  33333 | user    
> 14 |  88888 | biller  
> 14 |  55555 | user
```

Comment: Works perfectly! thank you so much!